# Pre-load Angular Component From URL/Query String

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

In my Angular app I have a component where I'm loading a grid view of some data being returned from the API. I also have some filters on the component, that the user can make use of to filter the data being returned.

This all works as expected -- until the user navigates away, and then returns to the component. At that point the filter selections are no longer being applied. In other words, the component is re-loaded in its "virgin" state, as if no filters had been selected.

So what I think I need to do is use ngOnInit() to read the url state from the browser window -- since all of the filters are still there at this point, as part of the query string, like so:

```
http://localhost:4200/consulting;page=1;pn_firstName.e=1;pn_firstName.v=John;pn_lastName.e=;pn_lastName.v=
```

According the above url/query string, the data should load after filtering on "firstName":"John".

So, my question is, what does the syntax look like in Angular to pre-load from the url like this within ngOnInit? Something like this?

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.router.navigateByUrl(`consulting/${}`); // Should be current url/query string in the browser window
}
```

Basically I just need to know what the syntax should look like when I want this to be read dynamically from the current state of the url/query string in the browser window. Because, that way, whatever filters had been applied will work accordingly upon re-load of the component -- because they're still available in the query string.

UPDATE:

After a comment below, I'm thinking I could do something like this:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

And then, because this is an `observable`, I'd do something like:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadData()
}

loadData() {
    this.router.navigate([this.route.queryParams.toArray()]);
}
```

Will something like this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject `activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute` into your component and the query params are available either through `activatedRoute.queryParams` or `activatedRoute.queryParamMap`.

See the [docs about router](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route).

Here is [simple stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dt5ekv) which just renders the query params and you can play with the [query parameters here](https://angular-dt5ekv.stackblitz.io/?test=5&name=Matt).

Comment: Thanks, I added some code as a follow-up above, but I think I'll update it to look more like what you have in your example.

Comment: When I try and use ParamMap, it's not finding it. Is this available in Angular 2?

Comment: No it is not. It is available in angular 4+.

Comment: But you can use `queryParams` in Angular 2. `queryParamMap` is just new and preferred way to access the query params.

Comment: Yes, I think you can use queryParams in Angular 2.